How to solve the problem of parameters count limit in Perforce trigger "pre-user-action"？
There is a Perforce trigger named "pre-user-action". It could do something before user's command.
So I tried to set a checker by:
pre_add_trigger command pre-user-add "python3 %//path/to/script.py% add %//path/to/Rule.json% %user% %client% %clientcwd% %args%"

It could prevent user mark for add in custom directory.
But when user try to add files more than a large number, an error
Operation user-add failed.
'pre_add_trigger' validation failed:
Too many options on command!

occured.
How can I avoid this error to run my script?
Can I split these parameters into several parts to execute my script separately?
I tried to use the %argc% to replace the %argv%, but it could not meet my needs.

This seems like a bug you should raise with Perforce support -- the arg limit on command triggers should be higher than the limit on the commands themselves.  Zooming out, though, you may want to use permissions to deny write access to the "custom directory" rather than using a trigger.
